# If statement that operates on the condition if a function returns None

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a decorator that just repeats a function a set number of times.
The decorator works completely fine, just one small issue.
When used on functions that don't return anything. It will print "None" after executing the function.
I know that when you print a function that doesnt return anything it just prints "None".

```
def repeat(r):
    """Decorator that repeats function 'r' number of times"""
    def repetition(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for x in range(r):
                rv = f(*args, **kwargs)
                print(rv)

        return wrapper

    return repetition


@repeat(2)
def output(msg):
    print(msg)


@repeat(3)
def addition(*args, result=0):
    for arg in args:
        result += arg

    return result


output("Hello")

addition(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Is it possible for me to have an if statement that checks if the function returns None and operates off of that? I would like to add a condition to the decorator so if a function returns nothing it wont print it, therefore stopping it from printing "None" every time it's used on a function that returns nothing.

For Example:

```
if function() == None:
        do something
```

Comment: *Don't* print in the wrapper function, that substantially reduces its reusability. Return a list of results, or read up on yield and generator functions generally.

Comment: `if rv` will solve that or `if rv is not None`. You just need to check the `thruthiness` of `rv` to make sure it's something you want to print.

Comment: If i return rv it ends the execution of that function, so i resorted to printing it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your

```
print(rv)
```

use

```
if rv is not None:
     print(rv)
```

The `None` value is a *singleton*, so instead of comparing its value with common operators `==`, `!=` (which is possible, but not recommended), compare it with `is` or `is not` operators.

---

*Note:*

In Python 3.8+ you may use the *walrus operator* (:=) for assigning a value and compare immediately using it in just *one expression*:

```
if (rv := f(*args, **kwargs)) is not None:
    print(rv)
```

Comment: You're welcome. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Documentation for the Python 3.8 option: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#assignment-expressions

Answer (score 1):

Just Check the `rv` result:

```
def repeat(r):
    """Decorator that repeats function 'r' number of times"""
    def repetition(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for x in range(r):
                rv = f(*args, **kwargs)
                if rv is not None:
                    print(rv)
                else:
                    ## Do domething if the function returns None
        return wrapper
    return repetition
```